# QDateTimeEdit blank with message QLineEdit::setSelection: Invalid start position (5)

Tags: qt

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDateTimeEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QDate>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *w = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(w);
    QDate date(2014, 6, 19);
    QDateTimeEdit *dateTimeEdit = new QDateTimeEdit((QDateTime)date);
    vLayout->addWidget(dateTimeEdit);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In the above application, when I change the month (hitting the cursor keys) to 10 the QDateTimeEdit gets blank (empty, numbers disapear!) and the application output shows the message:

```
QLineEdit::setSelection: Invalid start position (5)
```

Does it happen to anybody else? May I ask what's going on here?

Comment: works for me, does this code show the error for you or it's just a copy&paste from another function/class?

Comment: Set the input format using {QDateTimeEdit::setDisplayFormat()}

Comment: @techneaz, I did dateTimeEdit->setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); but it changes nothing. I'm missing the point?

Comment: @Miki, Yes, this code gives the error here.

Comment: The code you pasted  above works for me too without error. What is the Qt version?

Comment: Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32bit)